# How can I make QR codes that work with wallets like nami?

Tags: wallet, transaction, nami-wallet, transaction-metadata, payment

Im making payment gateways for crypto on non-web3 infrastucher. One of the ways I'm doing this is by making qr codes that after being scanned with a wallet fill in the transaction i.e. the amount of ADA the platform user sends to the platform and the receiving address.

I want to do this in a language that is compatible with my website i.e. python, javascript, CSS,HTML,PHP so I think only PHP/JS/Python are viable options.

How do I start with this? What should I do to make sure that the qr code is compatible with the wallets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the QR code data will need to match what each wallet is expecting eg receiving address.

Each wallet will handle the data differently and could expect different things. Some might expect address and amount, others might only expect address.
In this last case the wallet will use a second prompt for the amount, which can probably also be scanned if the wallet allows for it. So you could provide a second QR code containing only the amount data for the user to scan.

You will need to check the documentation on each wallet to see what they expect and how they handle it.

You could also install each wallet and test it out - there aren't that many wallets yet.

Usually the user will need to open their wallet and go into the payment area to then scan your QR code(s). Or are you wanting the user to scan your QR code and the wallet application start up and populate the address/amount details? This is more tricky.